# strange thing about strings comparison

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

This code:

```
        Console.WriteLine("~".CompareTo("a") > 0);
        Console.WriteLine('~'.CompareTo('a') > 0);
```

Gives me:

```
False
True
```

WTF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to show this behaviour is:

```
Console.WriteLine("a".CompareTo("b")); // -1 
Console.WriteLine("b".CompareTo("a")); // 1
Console.WriteLine('a'.CompareTo('b')); // -1 
Console.WriteLine('b'.CompareTo('a')); // 1

Console.WriteLine("~".CompareTo("a")); // -1
Console.WriteLine("a".CompareTo("~")); // 1
Console.WriteLine('~'.CompareTo('a')); // 29
Console.WriteLine('a'.CompareTo('~')); // -29
```

The difference may be subtle, but it is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhh2bx3h.aspx). The comparison in `Char.CompareTo(Char)` is

> based on
>   the encoded values of this instance
>   and value, **not their lexicographical
>   characteristics**.

At the same time, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w.aspx) for `String.CompareTo(String)`

> performs a word (case-sensitive and
>   culture-sensitive) comparison **using
>   the current culture**.

I.e. the first one bases the comparison on order, the latter on the default rules in the current culture (the order you might see in a dictionary).

Answer (score 8):

`myChar.CompareTo(otherChar)` compares two characters merely by their unicode values.

`myString.CompareTo(otherString)` uses a sort comparer of the current culture which may be implemented in a more lexical way.

Answer (score 2):

I think that `myString.CompareTo(otherString)` returns the same value as `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(myString,otherString,CompareOptions.None)`, i.e. does a culture-depending comparison.

In most cultures, non-alphabetic characters are sorted *before* letters, therefore `'~'` comes before `'a'`.

'char.CompareTo(otherChar)` on the other hand just compares the unicode values (i.e. 97 for 'a' against 126 for '~') and therefore returns a different result.

Answer (score 1):

To compare strings the same way as characters (by order of character code only) you have to use an ordinal comparison:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Compare("~", "a", StringComparison.Ordinal) > 0);
```

Output:

```
True
```